# Different results for functions generating list of numbers in Decimal type

Tags: python, decimal

For the task: Generate a list of numbers from 2 to 5.5 with a `step=0.5`, result data must be of a Decimal type.

I wrote two functions and I wonder **why results are different** (e.g. Decimal('4') and 
Decimal('4.0')).

The code is written in **Python 3.5**.

Here are the functions:

```
def generate_decimals(begin=2.0, end=5.5, step=0.5):
    nums_list = list(arange(begin, end + step, step))
    return [Decimal(number) for number in nums_list]


def generate_decimals2(begin=2.0, end=5.5, step=0.5):
    decimals = []
    num = Decimal(begin)
    while num <= end:
        decimals.append(num)
        num += Decimal(step)
    return decimals
```

Result for generate_decimals():

```
[Decimal('2'), Decimal('2.5'), Decimal('3'), Decimal('3.5'), Decimal('4'), Decimal('4.5'), Decimal('5'), Decimal('5.5')]
```

Result for generate_decimals2():

```
[Decimal('2'), Decimal('2.5'), Decimal('3.0'), Decimal('3.5'), Decimal('4.0'), Decimal('4.5'), Decimal('5.0'), Decimal('5.5')]
```

Is one of those results **more appropriate** than other??

Comment: For your first function, there is no need to turn "arange(begin, end + step, step)" into a list before doing list comprehension on the next line. You can simply do "return [Decimal(number) for number in arange(begin, end + step, step)]"

Comment: Would it be more appropriate when it comes to "best practices"?

Comment: Yes, because the list comprehension "[x for x in my_iterable]" only need an iterable to work. By casting the iterable into a list wastes memory and is really unnecessary. Check this post on more information and performance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227536/what-is-the-difference-between-range0-2-and-listrange0-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result is being implicitly casted in the second case (from `int` to `float`) after addition of `0.5`.

In the first case, each number is casted separately if needed, e.g. `3` doesn't have to be casted so it stays an integer type.

Of course both of those results are equally valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the "correct" code should be something like (in "full" Decimal):

```
def generate_decimals2(begin='2.0', end='5.5', step='0.5'):
    decimals = []
    num = Decimal(begin)
    while num <= Decimal(end):
        decimals.append(num)
        num += Decimal(step)
    return decimals
```